# setting height of label programmatically

Tags: objective-c, text, uilabel, text-size

I subclassed the uilabel so it would resize itself but for some reason my last word is being truncated to ...

Most of the time this works just fine but for some reason my sentence with x characters gets truncated and I dont understand why. Could somebody take a look at this?

```
    - (void)setFrame:(CGRect)newFrame {
    NSInteger maxNrOfLines = maxNumberOfLines == 0 ? 9999 : maxNumberOfLines;   
    NSString *text = self.text;
    UIFont *font = self.font;
    CGSize lineSize = CGSizeMake(newFrame.size.width, maxNrOfLines * font.lineHeight);
    CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:lineSize lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

    NSInteger lineCount = MIN(maxNrOfLines, MAX(1, size.height / font.lineHeight));
    CGFloat height = font.lineHeight * lineCount + 10;

    newFrame.size.height = height;
    super.frame = newFrame;
    super.numberOfLines = newFrame.size.height / font.lineHeight;
}
```

My sentence should be on 3 lines but it calculates only 2.

Comment: Have you checked whats the actual value of `maxNumberOfLines` and, as a result, value of `maxNrOfLines`? I may be missing something, but I don't see anything else that could cause this.

Comment: maxNumberOfLines = 9999
maxNrOfLines = 0

Eventually lineCount will be 2 with my sentance

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate height of UILabel accurately, you can use `sizeWithFont constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`
Example:

```
float width = 296;
CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(width, 9999);
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [yourText sizeWithFont:yourLabel.font constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize lineBreakMode:yourLabel.lineBreakMode];   
//set height of yourLabel to what we calculated 
CGRect frame = yourLabel.frame;
frame.size.height = expectedLabelSize.height;
yourLabel.frame = frame;
```

In this approach, we expect user to input **width**, **font** and **lineBreakMode** of UILabel and it returns expected frame size.